# How to prevent NULL from killing my ifelse vectorising?

Tags: r, vectorization

I would like to vectorize such function:

```
if (i > 0)
   fun1(a[i])
else
   fun2(i)
```

where `fun1, fun2` are already vectorized, and `a` is a vector.

My attempt:

```
ifelse(i > 0, fun1(a[i]), fun2(i))
```

However it is wrong!

```
> a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> i<-c(0,1,2,3)
> ifelse(i > 0, a[i], 0)
[1] 0 2 3 1 # expected 0 1 2 3
```

Do I have to use `sapply`? Is there any simple alternative that works?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong. `a[i]` evaluates to `c(1,2,3)` since `a[0]` is ignored. this is recycled to `c(1,2,3,1)` to match `length(i)`. So you get `0 2 3 1` from your `ifelse` because the first element of `i` is `FALSE`, and the other come from `a[i]` *recycled*.

There is a workaroud though: you can replace non-positive indices with `NA`:

```
> ifelse(i > 0, a[ifelse(i > 0, i, NA)], 0)
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Nevermind, I get it. `ifelse` cycles through both the `yes` and `no` options at each step of the logical vector, and doesn't start fresh within each group. E.g. - `ifelse(1:10 > 5, 1:10, 0)` giving `0,0,0,0,0,6,7,8,9,10`

Comment: I understand how recycling works. It is such a pain to get a workaround, need multiple duplicate `ifelse` to make it work, unless I use `Vectorize`